# How exactly does work inheritance of a class by an interface?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, interface

I am reading [this section of the TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#interfaces-extending-classes) and I am playing with modified example:

```js
class Control {
    public state: any;
}

interface SelectableControl extends Control {
    select(): void;
}

class Checkbox implements SelectableControl {
    public state: any;
    select() { }
}
```

This code is fine. But **Q1. I am not sure why I need to declare the property `state` in the `Checkbox` class since it exists already in the `SelectableControl` interface, really, why?**

More interesting things happen when I change the access modifiers. If I change it of the `state` property (in the `Control` and the `Checkbox`) to `protected`:

```js
class Control {
    protected state: any;
}

interface SelectableControl extends Control {
    select(): void;
}

class Checkbox implements SelectableControl {
    protected state: any;
    select() { }
}
```

then I get an error "Class "Checkbox" implements interface "SelectableControl" wrongly. The property "state" is protected, but the type "Checkbox" is not a class, inherited from "Control" class" (it's a translation to English). **Q2. What is the problem? Why I should inherit `Control` class if the `state` is already here, in the `SelectableControl`? How is it related to access modifier?!**

And now I change `protected` to `private`:

```js
class Control {
    private state: any;
}

interface SelectableControl extends Control {
    select(): void;
}

class Checkbox implements SelectableControl {
    private state: any;
    select() { }
}
```

and the error has been changed! Now it's "Class "Checkbox" implements interface "SelectableControl" wrongly. Types have separated declarations of private property "state"." (again, translation to English). **Q3. Why the error has changed?!**.

The concept that an interface can inherit a class looks very unfamiliar to me, so I cannot understand all these nuances...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is a structurally typed language, so when you inherit an interface from class it is equivalent to just copy-pasting the field / method definitions from a class to that interface, i.e.:

```js
// no extends, just copy-paste
interface SelectableControl { 
    public state: any;
    select(): void;
}
```

And you can see that in the output as well, that 2 classes end up not inheriting from each other:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=38&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7ALgJ3iaBvAsAKGkOgAcBXAIxAEthoJkxkBTALmjEQE8BufAX3z4qKJqgBmYYE2gBlJiCbAGlJghTpMTAB7NEAExhq0GbPiJ15i5AAoAlGwBu8Knt54BefKEiGAFooBrcngtaCoAW2IFcKYUGDkFJTAVIw1TAiIySho6BmY2Dh4zIghLJTtsaA8+IA

I believe this should answer all of the questions that you have, but if not I would be happy to expand.